# Do something after login success using RxJava and Retrofit 2

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, flatmap

I implemented the network call to validate the login, which is working fine. I am just facing some trouble doing another call to get user's data after the login is successful.

Here is the API call:

```
RestApi restApi = ServiceRest.createRetrofitService(RestApi.class, UrlServer.URL_SERVER);
Observable<Response<User>> responseObservable = restApi.getUser(user);
responseObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.i("LoginActivity", "[onCompleted]");
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Response<User> userResponse) {
                //Do stuff to go to another Activity
            }
        });
```

**------------- Edit #1 -------------**

I implemented what @Tassos suggested like this:

```
responseUser
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .map(new Func1<Response<User>, Observable<Response<Object>>>() {
                 @Override
                 public Observable<Response<Object>> call(Response<User> userResponse) {
                     Log.d("USER", userResponse.body().getName());
                     return restApi.getData(userResponse.body().getToken());
                 }
            })
            .doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error[doOnError]: " + throwable.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.i("LoginActivity", "[onCompleted]");
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onNext(Object result) {
                    Log.d("RESPONSE", result.toString());
                }
            });
```

Is it correct to do like this on subscribe method? Do I need to cast the Object result of onNext?

**//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//**

I want to, after the login is successful, call another url using the token obtained through the Response object User and send it to the other api call (`Observable<Response<Object>> getData(@Header("Authorization") String token);`) as an Authorization of the Header.
I have tried using flatMap and zip, but I wasn't able to accomplish this task.

Any advices? This concept is new to me.

Answer (score 4):

The `.flatMap` operator is perfect way to do one API call then another. Read about it here: http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/22/grokking-rxjava-part-2/ the "It Gets Even Better" part.

`.flatMap` allows you to change one observable with another one, i.e. make new API call using the result of previous one, implementing chain of events. If you do that, Subscriber will be called for an observable recieved from `.flatMap`.

You just write:

```
restApi.getUser(user)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .flatMap(userResponse -> restApi.getData(userResponse.getToken()))
    .doOnError(e -> Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
    .doOnTerminate(() -> progressDialog.dismiss())
    .subscribe(response -> proceedWithLogin())
```

Also why are you using `.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`? When you use retrofit observables, they usually generate one event, then complete, and there is no need of setting unsubscribe scheduler.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it is being returned "`java.net.SocketTimeoutException`" and then "`rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException`". I implemented the doOnError

Comment: Interesting. Is `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` caused by `getUser` or by `getData`? 
You can try do `.subscribe(response -> proceedWithLogin(), 
throwable -> Log.d("Error", throwable.getMessage())` because `OnErrorNotImplementedException` means that no error handling provided to Observable.

Comment: My guess is that `.doOnError` just gets called when error response is returned, but it does not substitute implementation of onError call of Subscriber.

Comment: I must stress that flatMap doesn't return items in order if the computation behind it is asynchronous. If you want to keep an order of your mapped observables use concatMap. http://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/

Answer (score 3):

Well, do you actually *need* the user to dismiss the dialog? Do you absolutely need to dismiss the dialog before doing the other calls?

```
    .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map(userResponse -> { /* do the other calls */ }
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<?>() {...
```

Comment: Actually I thought about it and I don't need to dismiss the dialog before doing the other call...I need to keep the dialog and change the message from "Validating user" to "Obtaining user's data", and by the end of the last call the dialog is dismissed. Thanks!
I am facing an issue trying to implement what you suggested, I will edit my question to show what I did